# How to get dataItem of modal window (Kendo-UI)

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I'm trying to get an instance of the current modal window (to save the data of the modal window to a file). But no success. I tried to do this via onActivate and then console.log($(this));

What is the correct method for doing this? Or I should have filled the data via template and then use content property of the kendoWindow ? THX!

**Grid:**

```
   $("#grid")
   .kendoGrid({
       dataSource: {
           transport: {
               read: {
                   url: "/api/GridData/GetCustomers",
                   dataType: "json"
               }
           }
       },    
       columns: [
                {
           command: { text: "View Details", click: viewDt  },
                    title: "View DT",
                    width: "100px"
                }
           ]
   });
```

**HTML:**

```
<form id="formViewDetail">
    Имя клиента:<br>
    <input type="text" name="ClientName" id="ClientNameViewDetail" value="">
    <br>

    ОКПО:<br>
    <input type="text" name="ClientOKPO" id="ClientOKPOViewDetail">
    <br>
    Дата регистрации:<br>
    <input type="text" name="RegistrationDate" id="RegistrationDateViewDetail">
    <br>
    Дата закрытия:<br>
    <input type="text" name="RemovalFromClientsDate" id="RemovalFromClientsDateViewDetail">
    <br>
    Комментарий:<br>
    <input type="text" name="Comment" id="CommentViewDetail">
    <br>
<button id="SubmitViewDetail">Сохранить</button> <button id="CloseViewDetail">Закрыть</button>
</form>
```

**Modal window:**

```
var myWindow = $("#window");

    myWindow.kendoWindow({
        width: "600px",
        title: "Редактирование данных клиента:",
        visible: false,
        actions: [
            "Pin",
            "Minimize",
            "Maximize",
            "Close"
        ],
        activate: onActivateWnd
        //close: onClose
    });

    function onActivateWnd(e) {
        console.log($(this)); 
    }
```

**Fill in data:**

```
       function viewDt(e) {
        var dItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
        console.log(dItem);
        myWindow.data("kendoWindow").center().open();
        //disabling input
        $("#formViewDetail").find("#ClientNameViewDetail").prop('disabled', true);
            $("#formViewDetail").find("#ClientOKPOViewDetail").prop('disabled', true);
            $("#formViewDetail").find("#RegistrationDateViewDetail").prop('disabled', true);
            $("#formViewDetail").find("#RemovalFromClientsDateViewDetail").prop('disabled', true);
            //passing data to form input
            $("#formViewDetail").find("#ClientNameViewDetail").val(dItem.ClientName);
            $("#formViewDetail").find("#ClientOKPOViewDetail").val(dItem.ClientOKPO);
            $("#formViewDetail").find("#RegistrationDateViewDetail").val(dItem.RegistrationDate);
            $("#formViewDetail").find("#RemovalFromClientsDateViewDetail").val(dItem.RemovalFromClientsDate);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The provided information suggests that the Window holds one data item from the Grid, which is displayed when the user clicks on a button inside a Grid row. In this case, it will be a lot easier to retrieve the desired information from the Grid's data item, instead of the Window's content. The Grid data item is available in the `dItem` variable.

If you want to save the Customer information after the user has edited it, then consider using the Grid's built-in popup editing and the `save` event. In this way, the Grid data item will always hold the latest values.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-save

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-popup

It is also possible to use popup editing with a custom popup edit form template:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-editable.template

Finally, in order to get a data item with the Kendo UI-related stuff inside, use `toJSON()` to get a plain object:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model#methods-toJSON